# Sending custom token on testnet doesn't appear on etherScan or recipient wallet

Tags: testnets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

The transaction is shown in my wallet with a blockcode. But when I clicked to go to etherscan.io, it said the transaction cannot be located. I searched with my address for all transactions, the custom token transfer is not in my list of transaction. Only the initial custom contract creation is.

In my wallet custom contract, I successfully queried the `balanceOf` the recipient using his address.

But he still cannot see the token.

Note that I have already made sure he is watching my custom token from his wallet. Reference: [Ethereum - use your coin](https://www.ethereum.org/token)

Tranx info:
Block *#0xfd996fa21924d6c76b7988ef673e26f8df2538c70d05907bf9fafd143713be0b*

From *0x02C1f35D018c66DDa45490A668d7E72e3bB03944* to *0x38d50DE4bD0a76c90074637bb5e3ed78B5E20332*

Comment: Could you post your address and the block number you are in the network?

Comment: Which testnet are you using?

Comment: Added address and block info; I switched to the only testnet on Wallet. From the menu bar - *Develop* -> *Network* -> *Testnet*

Answer (score 1):

The Ropsten testnet should be used with caution.

From the https://testnet.etherscan.io/ page:

> Announcement: There are currently at least 2 forks of the Ropsten
>   network, so depending on which fork you are connected to there might
>   be a mismatch of block data and transactions. Once the new TESTNET has
>   been decided by the community and made public, "testnet.etherscan.io"
>   will move over to the new testnet chain

This will likely be due to the recent spam attacks. I'm unsure how to go about checking which fork you're on.